# Interface/Inheritance/Delegate design issue

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

I have a set of messages, that all derive from Message, and implement the interface IMessage:

```
class Message : IMessage
{
   public string example1;
}

class LogOnMessage : Message
{
   public string password;
}

class LogOffMessage : Message
{
   public string anotherExample;
}
```

I have a messaging system, in which a proxy is able to detect incoming messages, and depending on the type of message, runs a delegate of the form

```
void MyDelegate(IMessage msg)
```

This is done by calling a handler registration function like this:

```
RegisterHandler(typeof(LogoffMessage),handler)
```

The implementation for this is simply a dictionary of the types, with each entry being a list of handlers: Dictionary< type, list< MyDelegate > >

Now, this is all fine, but of course the handler looks like this:

```
void MyHandler(IMessage msg)
{
   LogOffMessage lMsg = (LogOffMessage)msg;
   string athrEx = lMsg.anotherExample;

//Proceed with handling the logoff
}
```

Now, there's a couple of issues with this. One is that you might try to convert the Msg into the wrong type.

The other is that it's a bit inelegant to have to unwrap everything in the first few lines of any handler, rather than having handlers like this, **which I'd like to have**:

```
void MyDelegate(LogOffMessage msg)
```

What suggestions would you make?

I was thinking maybe instead of a dictionary of types, some other structure could be used to hold different delegate types, using generics. So there would be a MyDelegate < MsgType > list for each type. But it's not clear how to make a collection of collections, where each inner collection type is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your delegate generic:

```
delegate void MessageHandler<T>(T message) where T : IMessage
```

And make your `RegisterHandler` method generic:

```
void RegisterHandler<T>(MessageHandler<T> handler)
```

then call it with either:

```
RegisterHandler(handler); // Let type inference handle it
RegisterHandler<LogOffMessage>(handler); // State type argument explicitly
```

Then when you fetch the delegate by type, you can cast it to the right handler type - even though it's "unsafe" from the compiler's point of view, *you* know that you'll only have added the right kind of handler to the dictionary:

```
// When you populate this, create the appropriate type of
// `List<MessageHandler<T>>` based on the key
private Dictionary<Type, object> handlerMap;

void CallHandlers<T>(T message) where T : IMessage
{
    object value;
    if (handlerMap.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out value))
    {
        List<MessageHandler<T>> handlers = (List<MessageHandler<T>>) value;
        foreach (MessageHandler<T> handler : handlers)
        {
            handler(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that another alternative to using a `List<MessageHandler<T>>` is just to combine delegates and end up with a multicast delegate in the map for each type.